# Javascript - Randomized Prim's algorithm problemRandomized Prim's algorithm

Tags: javascript, maze, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to create a random maze generator in javascript.

There may already be working examples out there but I'm trying to solve this one myself (well, as much as possible)

The problem I'm having is my script only runs for a few blocks then stops.

I think the issue is with my understanding of the explanation I'm following (from this Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm)

This algorithm is a randomized version of Prim's algorithm.

1. Start with a grid full of walls.
2. Pick a cell, mark it as part of the maze.Add the walls of the cell to the wall list.
3. While there are walls in the list:

   1. Pick a random wall from the list. If the cell on the **opposite side** isn't in the maze yet:

      1. Make the wall a passage and mark the cell on the **opposite side** as part of the maze.
      2. Add the neighboring walls of the cell to the wall list.
   2. If the cell on the **opposite side** already was in the maze, remove the wall from the list.

As I've hi-lighted my problem is with the **opposite side**  part of this. Does this mean any adjacent cell that is in our wall list? Or does it mean something else?

I've tried it with adjacent cells and it ends up just blocking itself in.

Any idea's would be appreciated.

If I can get it working I'll post the code when it's done. Just as I said I want to get as far by myself before getting help with a full solution.

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such.

Comment: hahaha not at all! I been playing with an a* pathfinding algorithm and I wanted to make a maze for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wall represents the connection between two different cells. When you add a wall to your wall list, it's because you are visiting a cell that will be part of your maze, so when it refers to the opposite one it means the cell 'behind' that wall, where a passage would lead to if that wall was not there.

Comment: Ahh i see this may be where i'm falling down. My walls are just another blocks. Can I still apply this  algorithm?

Comment: Well, the algorithm doesn't specify any implementation details, so as far as you are consistent with the way you represent cells and walls and the way you treat them, then you shouldn't have any problem

Comment: hmmm I maybe looking at this all wrong.. I'm seeing at is as I have a 10 x 10 square.. I select a block in that square and set it as my starting block. I add the 4 blocks around that to my walls list.. and apply the algorithm.. Though from what every example I've seen and from what I guess your saying.. this is wrong?

Comment: It is wrong if you intend that every block represents a cell, as you would be using them as walls. What I just said before is that it's not wrong if you DO want it to be that way, and so are consequent with that choice. Indeed, that's not the natural approach, so odds are that you won't want it to be that way. In that case, you'll have 2 different data structures, one for representing the cells (let's say a n * m matrix) and another one for representing the walls (a list of pair of coordinates, each one representing the location of a cell, and each pair representing the two walls connected)

Comment: I'm with you. What i've been missing is any direction calculation. 

Thanks for your help